# Issue with mod_rewrite when accessing directory

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

My code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I am using WAMP and had setup a Virtual Host.
In my index.php, there is code to get page passed and checks if it exists(in database). If not, display an error message. It works fine.

Eg: `http://mysite/contactus/`

But it will not work if I use a a directory name as page_name in the URL. Eg: `http://mysite/images/`. This will display page not found error (ie. checks database and no page found, so display "not found"). But it will not display images,css(linked file) in the page. Also, it shows `http://mysite/images/?page=images` in addressbar.

Like that, if I goto `js` folder which is used to store javascript files, above problem occurs. So, problem is caused if any subdirectory's name is passed as pagename.

How to solve this ?

When `http://mysite/images/` is supplied, mod_rewrite is redirecting to `http://mysite/images/index.php?page=images` instead of `http://mysite/index.php?page=images`

**Edit**
Please tell me how to block hotlinking of files and directory, and redirect back to index page or send some browser header error ?

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**Edit**
New code(semi-working):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# remove trailing slash ONLY if it is not an existing folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteRule ^article/([a-z]+)/?$  http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This code will clear the problem with not displaying pics and css when a directory name is mentioned. But whatever pagename i specify eg:`http://mysite/contactus`, it will goto URL: `http://mysite/index.php?page=contactus`. Even if I use a directory name eg: `http://mysite/js`, it will goto: `http://mysite/index.php?page=js`

I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/*$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

you have to put the slash in front.

---

Edit: changed the ? to *

Comment: thank you. That will solve `http://mysite/images/?page=images` problem. Now it will show only `http://mysite/images/`. But images are still not displaying. Also, if I put, `http://mysite/images` (no slash at end), it will still show `http://mysite/images/?page=images`

Comment: Yes. I tried "*" also. Still images (inside html) are not displayed. But `http://mysite/images/?page=images` problem is corrected for `http://mysite/images/`. Not for `http://mysite/images` (no slash at end)

Comment: @VppMan: maybe you should write ([a-z]+)\/*, maybe escapement problem

Comment: i donot wish to allow hotlinking or directory listing. So, I have to include code for preventing that and it will solve my present problem ?

Comment: what happens when you remove the / does it matches images?

Comment: which slash ? Escaping slash ?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

Comment: I checked image's location. It is listed as: `http://mysite/images/images/logo.png`. So, picture files and css file assumed to be in `http://mysite/images/`. But in reality, they reside in `http://mysite/` folder ! So, that is why images and css are not working when a directory name is there.

Comment: actually, why do you want to use PHP to read those files, is there a particular reason?

Comment: what are you talking about ? What i am doing is, page name will be displayed in url and this will be matched and it is redirected to `index.php` which resides in root folder, along with pagename as a GET variable(called `page`). If this page exists in database,  some content will be displayed. This work fine if I donot use a url with a subdirectory name in place of page name.

Comment: If i explicitly use {HTTP_HOST} like this: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?page=$1 [L]`, it would show the index page with css and pics working properly. But url shows like `http://mysite/index.php?page=js`. And i will redirect to index page if user requests a folder using: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1/ [R]` I will update code in first post now.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your script is for documents only, not images or other resources.

Then you should ignore them right away. Try adding this line right after `RewriteBase` like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /rewrite/
RewriteRule ^/(images|js)/(.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Then these subdirectories would be served right away, thus bypassing the next `RewriteRule` set.

Comment: It is not working. Also, I do not wish to hardcode directory names, because there will be more dirs.

Comment: @Vpp Man : but it *does* work with your Rule set, I checked on my own server. Please see my edited answer for clarity. I can understand if you wish not hardcode any dirnames.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem with the directories I usually force a slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+[^/])$    $1/ [R]
```